# Get class and instance DescriptionAttribute values

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

How do you retrieve the `DescriptionAttribute` of an instance of a class and of the class itself?

```
[Description("The Help class description")]
public class Help
{
    //...
}

public class General
{
    [Description("The Help instance description")]
    public Help ThisHelp {get; set;} = new Help();
}

public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        General MyGeneral = new General();
        var Atts = MyGeneral.ThisHelp.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Atts.OfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Select(a => a.Description)));
        //Only writes "The Help class description" ... But not the instance
    }
}
```

I get the class version only.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the attribute of the instance, per se, since instances don't have attributes. It's the attribute of the *property*. So, you need to have a `MemberInfo` of the target property in order to get its attributes, not just the attributes of the `Help` type.

Try something like this:

```
var propertyAtts = MyGeneral.GetType().GetProperty("ThisHelp")
                        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);
```

You could also use `typeof(General)` instead of `MyGeneral.GetType()` in case you don't have an instance of `General`. Similarly, for the class attributes, you may use `typeof(Help)` instead of `MyGeneral.ThisHelp.GetType()`.

Comment: Excellent clarification in the terminology, which makes the implementation clearer. I am using this to display the descriptions in a custom Settings editor where I wanted to show both descriptions to the user as they click on each property in my GUI representation.

Comment: @John Well, you now have `Atts` and `propertyAtts`; you can use them however you want (e.g., join them, etc.)... use `Atts.Concat(instanceAtts)` if you want them in one collection, for example.